# 403 Forbidden when file permissions are correct

Tags: php, nginx

I'm trying to create a server on nginx with multiple laravel (a php framework) sites under the same subdomain `labs.rasouza.com.br/cdm`, `labs.rasouza.com.br/app2`, `labs.rasouza.com.br/app3`, etc.

nginx and php are properly configured to run as `web` user, and my root folder is under `/home/web`:

```
drwxrwxrwx  5 web web 4.0K Aug 18 13:56 cdm
-rwxr-xr-x  1 web web   24 Aug 12 02:53 info.php
drwxr-xr-x 13 web web 4.0K Aug 12 04:15 owncloud
drwxr-xr-x  2 web web 4.0K Aug 18 15:23 tmp
```

My sites-available are configured like this:

```
server {
        listen   80;

        root /home/web;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name labs.rasouza.com.br;

        access_log /home/web/tmp/labs.access.log;
        error_log /home/web/tmp/labs.error.log;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location ~ ^/cdm/(.+\.php)$ {
                alias /home/web/cdm/current/public/;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                include fastcgi_params;

        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on the php-fpm socket
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;

        }


}
```

Whenever I try to access `labs.rasouza.com.br/cdm` I get the `403 Forbidden` page and the error log is: `directory index of "/home/web/cdm/" is forbidden`. When I try to access `info.php` it goes ok. File permissions are also ok, `web` user owns everything

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you access files inside the `cdm` folder? For example, if `/home/web/cdm` exists and you open `labs.rasouza.com.br/cdm` does it work?

Comment: yep! I even tried to set it to 777 but the error is just the same

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask if you have `/home/web/cdm/foo.php` and browse `labs.rasouza.com.br/cdm/foo.php` does that work? I am not sure how I forgot to write the important part of that comment :/

Comment: I moved `info.php` to `cdm/` folder and I got a wierd error: `FastCGI sent in stderr: "Access to the script has been denied (see security.limit_extensions)"`. Then I tried a simpler example (with HTML files only) and tried to access `labs.rasouza.com.br/test/index.html` and got: `rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html"`